# How "verbrauchen" and "aufbrauchen" are used to mean spend?

Tags: synonym, verb-usage

I know that both mean "to use up" and "to consume"

I have made my research where "verbrauchen" and "aufbrauchen" mean "to spend"!!

How can they mean "to spend" ?

I would be thankful for an answer.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with the sentence ' How could these words be used as aufwenden?', could you explain it? Then I can include it in my answer.

Comment: I have made an edit.

Comment: Why shouldn't they mean "to spend"? I don't understand your question.

Comment: @Robert The main meaning is "to consume" but how are they used as "to spend"

Comment: You need to give us whole and unambiguous example sentences, otherwise it’s hard to impossible to understand what you mean. Words just have so many different meanings.

Comment: @Philipp I am asking for a sentence where verbrauchen and aufbrauchen come in the meaning "to spend", I want to know if these two words mean "to spend"

Comment: I tried my best to edit my answer. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To the original question:
In general you are right that *verbrauchen* and *aufbrauchen* describe the consumption of something. Let me specify this in an example:

> Karls Auto verbraucht Benzin. Wenn er nicht tankt, dann wird das Auto das Benzin aufbrauchen. Dann ist alles Benzin verbraucht/aufgebraucht.
>  
>   Karl's car uses fuel. If he doesn't refill it, the car will use up the fuel. Then all the fuel is used up/consumed.

Therefore, *aufbrauchen* is a special case of *verbrauchen*, where in the end nothing is left. Note that *verbrauchen* can also be used in that sense. *aufbrauchen* is also a bit more colloquial.

*Aufwenden* does not fit in the context here, since it refers to *spend/expend*.

To the edit:

> Sie kaufte immer mehr Süßigkeiten und *brauchte* so ihr ganzes Geld *auf*.
>   She bought more and more sweets and *spent* all her money that way.
>
> Er verbraucht so viel Geld beim Einkaufen!
>   He *spends* so much money shopping!

I think *verbrauchen/aufbrauchen* are only used in the sense of *to spend* when you talk about money. Though you would usually use *ausgeben* in these occasions.

*Aufwenden* is not as frequently used as *verbrauchen*. On the other hand, it's a bit more formal, which is why it appears relatively often in [books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=aufwenden%2Cverbrauchen%2Caufbrauchen&year_start=1800&year_end=2018&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caufwenden%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cverbrauchen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caufbrauchen%3B%2Cc0). As far as I know it is mostly used for time and money. A typical example is

> Wir müssen dafür viel Zeit und Geld *aufwenden*.
>   We have to *spend* much time and money on that.

[This post](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/41607/whats-the-equivalent-noun-for-spending-expenditure) is also very related to this topic.