# What's the equivalent noun for "spending/expenditure"?

Tags: english-to-german

I don't mean here  the amount of money to be spended but the action of spending money.

What is also the noun for "expense" and here I mean the amount of money to be spended?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Example sentences would be helpful. As is, I don’t understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 5):

> Ich habe im Urlaub viel Geld **ausgegeben**.

*I've spent much money during holidays.*

> Meine **Ausgaben** waren hoch.

*My expenses were high.*

---

There's also another set of verbs and nouns, which sounds a bit stilted:

> Ich musste dafür viel Geld **aufwenden**.

*I had to spend a lot of money on it.*

> Der finanzielle **Aufwand** war hoch.

*The financial effort was high.*